# Can balanced accept Bank Account other than country US?

Tags: balanced-payments

Can balanced accept bank account from other countries apart from US?

If yes how the routing numbers and account number format should be?

Also

When am creating a test bank account using balanced.js, the account type is set to 'checking' even though i sent type as 'savings'. Is the test bank account always has type 'checking'?

Answer (score 0):

No.

https://support.balancedpayments.com/hc/en-us/articles/200135940-Is-Balanced-available-internationally-

https://support.balancedpayments.com/hc/en-us/articles/201886494-International-ACH-Transfers-IATs-Not-currently-available-

As for the account type issue make sure you pass "account_type" instead of "type" for balanced.js v1.1.